# How to set up autoUnmask for jquery inputmask?

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I have placed a currency input mask on the textbox.

But when the form is submitted, the leading '$' sign and the separating commas need to be removed so that the value can be binded to as a decimal.

Here is how I set the autoUnmask as described in [here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#set-a-value-and-apply-mask).

```
$('[data-mask="currency"]').inputmask({alias:"currency",'autoUnmask':true});
```

which doesn't appear effective.

What is the correct way to set up `autoUnmask`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `autoUnmask:true`, we should use `removeMaskOnSubmit:true`.